# compile error when using two typename in template class

Tags: c++, compilation-errors

I am using Arduino 1.8.5 ide. I am just creating a class with two typename which name is "Map". This class takes all int and String variations. Like;

```
class Map<int, int>;
class Map<int, String>;
class Map<String, int>;
class Map<String, String>;


Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();
```

If I create instance of this class like above in Main.ino file then everything is ok. But if I create it another file with .h extension which is "Test.h" then compilation fails. These are files;

### Main.ino

```
#include "Map.h"
#include "Test.h"

Test *test = new Test();
Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();


void setup() {

}

void loop() {

}
```

### Map.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Map.h"

template<typename E, typename T> Map<E, T>::Map()
{

}


template class Map<int, int>;
template class Map<int, String>;
template class Map<String, int>;
template class Map<String, String>;
```

### Map.h

```
#ifndef Map_h
#define Map_h

#include "Arduino.h"

template<typename E, typename T> class Map {

public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
};

#endif
```

### Test.h

```
#ifndef _Test_h
#define _Test_h


#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Map.h"

class Test
{
public :
    Test();
    ~Test();
    Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();
};

#endif
```

Error is;

```
In file included from C:\Users\zafer\Desktop\Main\Main.ino:3:0:
Test.h:14: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
  Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();

                                        ^

Test.h:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
  Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();

                                              ^

Test.h:14: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();

                                   ^

In file included from C:\Users\zafer\Desktop\Main\Main.ino:2:0:
Map.h:6: error: provided for 'template<class E, class T> class Map'
 template<typename E, typename T> class Map {

                                        ^
exit status 1
expected ';' at end of member declaration
```

Sorry, If it's been already resolved and I couldn't find it.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I put the error in question.

Comment: What MCU/board are you using? AVR? ESP8266? Something else?

Comment: the errors indicate that it doesn't know what a 'String' is; 'string' is usually spelled in lowercase. n.b. not sure about string classes on arduino

Comment: Map.cpp has a ; missing at the end of the template.

Comment: I added ; to Main.cpp and I am still getting same error. I am using Arduino/Genuino Uno board. By the way, if I create instance like; Map<String, int> *list = new Map<String, int>(); then no compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this class declaration:

```
class Test
{
public :
    Test();
    ~Test();
    Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();
};
```

This line is wrong:

```
    Map<int, String> *list = new Map<int, String>();
```

You can't execute procedural code when declaring a class. That has to go into the constructor or some other function.

For example, this compiles without errors:

### Test.h

```
#ifndef _Test_h
#define _Test_h


#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Map.h"

class Test
{
public :
    Test() { list = new Map<int, String>; } ;
    ~Test();
    Map<int, String> *list;
};

#endif
```